# Setting forms authentication redirect Url per Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have a project layout like:

```
Areas | Admin 
Areas | FrontEnd
```

I want to `[Authorize]` users per area (as Admin will use a different table to users in `FrontEnd`. When I use the `[Authorize]` tag in a Controller in my Admin area, it redirects me to the forms authentication login url which is set in the **root** web.config file.

Is it possible to override this per **area**? I see each area has a Web.config file but it seems to ignore the forms authentication setting if I add it in there.

If I am approaching this in the wrong way, I am happy to take some advice.

Edit:

I have tried something but don't know if it's best practice. Basically, implement my own `CustomAuth` attribute and redirect:

```
public class CustomAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Account");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with my own `[Authorise]` attribute and redirecting on Unauthorised access.

```
public class AuthorizeArea : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Admin/Account");
    }
}
```